# A mismatch between tf trees presented in Rviz2 and tf2_tools view_frames

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, tf2, ros-humble

I spawned a robot model into gazebo classic, while using ROS2 Humble.

The robot spawns and moves, its all good on this side.

But when I wish to view the tf tree on Rviz2 I get status warnings and some of the links are missing.

[image]

So I ran the command `ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames` and checked the output. And the tree graph in the PDF looks good to me.

[image]

Moreover, when i set the "Fixed Frame" to "base_footprint" instead of "world", at the Rviz displays, suddenly the whole tree is connected and I can see all of the frames without warnings.

[image]

What could possibly be the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the screenshots, your `odom`->`base_footprint` transform is published in simulated time, while the wheel transforms are in current time.

That stops TF from building a transform from wheels frame to the world, just because it cannot time of the TFs is very different. It also explains why switching Fixed Frame to the `base_link` helps: you remove `odom`->`base_footprint` from the equation.

Comment: I see what you mean, Thanks!